# Ubuntu 21.04 Host - Windows 10 Guest VMWare 16 Workstation Player frequently freezing entire system necessitating hard shutdown

Tags: boot, windows-10, vmware, 21.04

I'm a relatively new convert from Windows; but there are still some applications that I use for work that don't have a straightforward alternative in Linux, e.g. ABBYY Fine Reader and OneNote (the online version and electron Linux version is still no match for the desktop version, which offers more features).

After a trial period, I felt confident enough with Ubuntu that I erased and reformatted my hard drive entirely and installed Ubuntu. I set up a VM for Windows 10 (200GB total space). When I upgraded from Ubuntu 20.1 to Ubuntu 21.04, there were initially no issues. Then I intermittently got the blue screen of death in the VM and had to restart the VM. Now the VM frequently causes the entire system to freeze, usually at boot or shortly after entering my user login password, forcing a hard reset because in most instances CTRL + ALT + DEL doesn't work, ALT + F2 doesn't work and probably 8/10 times ALT + PrtScrn + REISUB doesn't work either. I've tried leaving it; but, 20 minutes later still frozen. Usually Windows will boot successfully after 2-3 attempts; but, this is annoying the crap out of me due to the amount of wasted productivity. I thought it may be the NVIDIA drivers so I switched to the Xorg (Wayland doesn't appear as an option with my device, an Acer Aspire F15 F5-572G-70FJ). I thought I was onto something when two times running I was able to start the VM without problem, then ... same crapola.

I'm not a programmer so need explicit direction what to input, preferably via copy-paste into terminal. I tried re-installing vmware player; but, no difference. I really don't want to delete my vm, if I can help it; because that would mean I would have to erase and reinstall the OS as I haven't a working snapshot with VM in Hirsute Hippo. Suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with a Windows 10 guest on an upgraded Ubuntu 21.04 Host.
It works quite well until the host is suspended and on resuming, it seems that there are some trouble with shared folders...
On resuming host before resuming (Windows 10) guest, it's ok, I've the access to my shared resource which is a MMC card, mounted by its blkid (after I had reinstalled my ubuntu drivers)
But now,
On resuming host after Windows 10 guest resuming, the access from the host is slow, cpu is high on vmx, and the guest is very slow, ver slow to take a Alt-Ctrl-Supp, then the access to the content of the mounted resource freezes again my guest...
I can't update my vmtools on the guest, the choice is unvailable
My host and my guest are up-to-date

Comment: The problem is the usb drivers. A message comes up at boot and, if I press cancel, windows 10 runs perfectly in vm ... no more freezing. Don't hit okay or close X or the vm goes into freeze. Obviously a vmware issue not ubuntu.